# Add foreign keys to database in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

Using `PostgreSQL`, i know Rails not use foreign keys in database and handle all relations through [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) has_one, has_many.... and many else, and i know there is gems like [Foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) that can help with this,

But is it worth speed wise to add foreign keys to database tables And why someone may care to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that [foreign key constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) are a tool to ensure data integrity and consistency.

Whereas a [database index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) is used to speed up queries.

They seem similar and are often used in the same context, but they are not the same.

---

And btw there is no need to use a gem like Foreigner. Foreign keys are supported since Rails 4.2 out of the box. Have a look at [`add_foreign_key`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key):

```
add_foreign_key :posts, :users
```

Or you could use the `foreign_key` that is available on the `belongs_to` and the `references` datatype:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: i think you are right in this point, Data integrity and consistency, is the main reason behind foreign keys in rails app database.

Answer (score 1):

Rails (or ActiveRecord) is just a simple ORM around entries in a database. It does not utilize most features that a DB provides. Partly because they want to be DB agnostic and a lot of more advanced features are DBM specific. But also because some people believe that putting logic into DBs is the root of all evil.

This does not mean that everything is evil, but that it should be used with care. Especially stored procedures. That said, I believe, that foreign key constraints and indices are underused in Rails. There are not many drawbacks to creating them (besides from seeding).

You can for example utilize unique key constraints on has-one relations to prevent multiple records. Rails does not do it by default. You can rely on validations but utilizing the DB is the safer option:

```
add_index :child_table, [:parent_id], unique: true
```

You can also utilize foreign key constraints to automatically let the DB delete dependen records:

```
add_foreign_key :children, :parents, column: :parent_id, dependent: :delete
```

You can combine both:

```
add_foreign_key :children, :parents, column: :parent_id, dependent: :delete, index: { unique: true }
```

There are a lot more ways to utilize the DB to ensure data integrity and consistency.

If you nowadays create a rails migration with a reference it actually creates an index and a foreign key constraint for you:

```
 ~blog $ rails g model Post author:references title:string content:text

Running via Spring preloader in process 33539
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160308141214_create_posts.rb
      create    app/models/post.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/post_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/posts.yml

~/blog $ cat db/migrate/20160308141214_create_posts.rb

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the relations of ActiveRecord need a foreign key in the database. By convention, it's name is `{table}_id`.

Documentaiton : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association
(look for keyword 'migration')

EDIT :

Adding an index on columns can actually help you make faster queries. PostgreSQL automatically creates an index for each primary key constraint, but it is not necessary to add a foreign key constraint to have an indexed column.

So as long as you have indexes on your `id` and `{table}_id` columns, there is no need to add a foreign_key constraint just to speed up the querying.

Comment: A column name following that a convention is not the same as a [FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in the database.

Comment: oh right, I didn't understood that. I'm updating my answer